# IE7, and possible IE8, will only run *some* JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I'm experiencing a problem on a test-machine which is running in a quite restrictive environment.

I only have the option of running IE 7 on this machine, which is used for testing purposes. And I cannot install anything on it. I don't have access to Developer-tools in Internet Explorer, so I can debug in any way, except maybe using "javascript:" in the addressbar.

**The Problem**

On the page I am displaying in IE 7 on this machine i use the jQuery 1.8 Datepicker widget. This loads up fine, and all settings appear to be as they are supposed to.

I can toggle if it is displayed on not using a button. But when the widget is displayed, and I attempt to page between months, nothing happens. It is not a problem in production nor in Development. Only on this test-machine.

Does anyone have a clues as to what might be the restricting factor that blocks *some* JavaScript, but not *other* JavaScript.

My initial thought is it is the browser.

If anyone has some experience with this, I'd love to hear your input. If you have an idea what might be the problem let me know :-)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what happens when you go to the jqueryUI site and test it there? do you have the same problems?
it could be the security restrictions / policy on IE itself, but you'll only know if you test it against another site hosting the same code.

is all your code locally hosted or do you rely on some cdn-based scripts?
do you have any antivirus on the machine? perhaps that's interfering.

the only other thing i could think of would be an issue with query strings on the end of script calls being cut off/disallowed by the browser... i know that some plugins are loaded via query string with certain js frameworks.

Comment: It's all hosted locally. Actually I am debugging this for someone, and I asked the same question, if it's CDN-hosted. But it isn't.

Comment: I'll try on Monday and see what happens on the jqueryui-site.

I'm on my home-box now, and toying with the options and doing exactly that on the jqueryui-site. I have come across exactly the same result of the problem but using a different widget (the accordian), where instead of running the script, it simply updates the address in the adressbar with an appended # to the existing URL.

Comment: Seems the problem was the very restrictive environment that the test-server was hosted in. And the test-environment did not match the test environment. Admin-fail :-(